# Install Yeoman Generator from Git

Tags: git, installation, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am working on a Yeoman Generator that is specifically designed for my needs (e.g. maybe useless for others). This is the reason why I don't want to publish it on npm. My question now is, if there is a good way to provide a good way to install the generator using a Git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your package, but don't publish it however push it to your git repository and then you can execute this command:

```
npm install git://my-repo-url/mygenerator.git
```